# Quaternion rotation

Tags: opengl, quaternion

I have a problem understanding quaternions rotation in OpenGL.
So far I have implemented all function and operators related to quaternions.They are definitely working right!.
However I can't find where I'm making the mistake within rotation function.

Let's say I have a a cube in 3d space at (xyz)`(1, 5, 2)` if I am not wrong the position in 4D is `p = 0 + i + 5j + 2k`, and the orientation and rotation `(0, 0, 0, 0)` in 4D space is `q = 1 + 0i + 0j + 0k`

Now I want to rotate it by 30 degrees along y-axis.

```
q = cos(a / 2) + (ix + jy + kz)sin(a/2)
```

So 30 degrees along y-axis is `q=0.96+0.25j` now:

```
Pout = q * Pin * con(q)

Q = q * Pin = (0.96 + 0.25j) * (0 + 1i + 5j + 2k) = -1.25 + 1.46 + 4.8 + 1.67
```

Shall I normalize it now or not?

```
conj(q) = 0.96 - 0.25j
Pout = Q * con(q) = 0 + 1.81 + 4.92 + 1.32
```

Normalized:

```
q = 0 + 0.33i + 0.91j + 0.22k
```

This is definitely the wrong answer according to [this site](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToQuaternion/program/index.htm)

Rotating the object along the Y-axis by 30 degrees from a point `(0,0,0)` gives the correct result just by computing `q`. If I use the above algorithm and multiply it by `Pin` I get `(0,0,0,0)`

Can you show me how to do it right step by step?

Also how do I to orbit one point along another. Lets say I have the given point above and I want it to orbit around the point `(2, 10, -2)` using quaternions.

And when I manage to get the correct quaternion, how do I use it in the proper way along with openGL `glRotatef`?

So far my program runs like this:

1. Quaternion = x, y, z of object
2. Compute Rotation by X degrees along axes.
3. Quaternion to Axis Angle
4. `glRotatef` (by result of point 3)
5. Quaternion = result of point 2
6. Go to point 2
7. Go to step 1

Do I always have to change quaternions to Axis-angles, or is there another way which allow me to represent the rotation without conversion?

Comment: a quaternion is just an orientation. when applied to a point, and or a vector then it has meaning. like saying 37 degrees about X-axis where did your start from. then your question on orbit. define your orbit plane (or are we talking about parametric equation orbits?) I might venture a ques that your using quaternions to learn about them, and because they "sound cool".

Comment: If you want a working quaternion implementation, I've made my own library awhile ago to use with OpenGL - https://github.com/ThePiachu/Space-Combat/blob/master/Space%20Combat/math/quaternion.h .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations **are correct**. Maybe you missed it, but here's your vector, rotated 30 degrees around the Y axis:

```
Pout=Q*con(q)=0+1.81+4,92+1.32
```

You **must not normalise** the result, that's all. Note that you seem to be having precision problems, because this is what I get:

```
             v = [1 5 2]
             q = [.965926 0 .258819 0]
            ~q = [.965926 0 -.258819 0]
     q * [0 v] = [-1.294095 1.483564 4.829629 1.673033]
q * [0 v] * ~q = [0 1.866025 5 1.232051]
            v' = [1.866025 5 1.232051]
```

If you want to orbit around a given point, just subtract that point from your source point, perform the rotation usings quaternion arithmetics, and add the point back at the end. Using your values above:

```
            p1 = [1 5 2]
            p2 = [2 10 -2]

   v = p1 - p2 = [-1 -5 4]
q * [0 v] * ~q = [0 1.133975 -5 3.964102]
            v' = [1.133975 -5 3.964102]

 p1' = p2 + v' = [3.133975 5 1.964102]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Lets say I have a a cube in a point of 3d space (x=1,y=5,z=2) if I am not wrong the position in 4D is p=0+i+5j+2k orientation and rotation (0,0,0,0) in 4D q=1+0i+0j+0k now I want to rotate it by 30 degree along y axis.

Nothing in this statement after the words "if I am not wrong" made any kind of sense.

You do not use quaternions to encode positions (unless you're using dual-quaternions and you're not). A quaternion, for the purposes of graphics, is nothing more than a fancy way to encode a rotation matrix. It is just an encoding of an orientation in space.

So there is no quaternion position.

Since you're using fixed-function rendering, if you want to apply a quaternion to the matrix stack, then you do it by generating a matrix from it and applying it to the stack with `glMultMatrix`. If you want to rotate an object's position based on a quaternion, then you `glMultMatrix` the quaternion onto the stack, then `glTranslate` the position onto the stack.

And you should never "change quaternions to Axis angle". There is never any reason to do so.

Comment: I have to disagree with you here. *Unit quaternions* are used to encode an orientation in space. *Quaternions* as they are are just 4D objects, and it is perfectly valid to use the `w=0` hyperplane (which is a 3D subset of the 4D set of quaternions) to encode a position.

Comment: @Sam: Mathematically valid, yes. But of zero utility in this situation. Do you honestly think that the OP understands the mathematical validity of the concept?

Comment: True, OP seems to be confused about what quaternions are useful for. But other people may read that and get the wrong idea. As for “changing quaternions to axis angle”, I wouldn't really recommend against it since it's a quick way to generate a matrix on the stack with `glRotate`. But yeah, again, probably not the best advice to OP.